# Code in comments not properly rendered

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

I typed `` ` | "a"` `` into a comment, but it didn't render as code.  Instead, it just appears as regular text.  See the comments below for examples.

Comment: proof: ` | "a"`

Comment: ` | "a"` gets code formatting?  Didn't notice the leading space.  But without the space in front of the pipe, it is formatted: `| "a"`.

Comment: your comment got formatted when I first saw it, but not after reloading the page

Comment: Yeah I was editing it when I noticed the leading space.

Comment: Ah, yes. It's still there after a hard reload, so it's (probably) not a stale js cached.

Comment: Intersting.  The backticks also fail the render the leading space in your question too.

Comment: True, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Test comment: leading space before pipe in backticks: ` |`  Leading space before any content: ` a`.  Ok I guess any leading space creates a problem.  You might check MSE and see if this has been previously reported.

Comment: spaces around ascii text: ` a `

Comment: Found an [MSE explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125764/why-dont-these-back-ticks-format-code-in-comment/125768#125768)

Comment: It's still a bug. I wanted to include the space in the quote since it was important to the question.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Shadow Wizard's MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125764/why-dont-these-back-ticks-format-code-in-comment/125768#125768), spaces immediately after the opening backtick or immediately before the closing backtick will break the code rendering in comments.  Within a post you can use `<code>` blocks instead of backticks to render the stuff properly  `| "a"`, but comments don't support `<code>` blocks.

Yes, this is a bug.  I'm not sure what a solution would require.  For now a workaround would just be to avoid using spaces next to backticks.  For your comment, providing the surrounding code context might be better (`endOfCondition | "a"`).